Automatically mount external hard disk : terminal shortcut or any script?
following up previos question I am anble to kount hard disk but now follow up question is that can we have any command/script/alis or feature so that whenever we insert external HDD and it mounted;
curently I can check with below command

sudo blkid show


/dev/sda1: LABEL="Seagate Backup Plus Drive" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="D012032A120314DE" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="db2dad7b-01"

but when try with grep 'Segate'

sudo blkid show | grep 'Segate'

it doesnt show any output; how can we get the sepecific one
now main question is; can we mount automatically as everytime I have to mount by check disk address and then use mount
can we create any shortcut aur alias; I want that if external hard disk attached then running that command will automatically mount the HDD.

How is this different then the other question you just asked about using this disk?

apologies but This is consecutive question; that question was how to mount and now it is how to make it automatically mounted. and why I ask seprate question because If I add this question in that question then people downvote and suggest to ask one question only in one question. ideally it can be next follow up question but this is how it is SO manages now a days.

Your grep ccommand is looking for "Segate", but the product is "Seagate".

This question is similar to: How to auto mount my external hard drive?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

NTFS config is obsolete. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654952/consistent-auto-mount-of-external-hard-drive

@user68186 that answer is 14 years old and now ubuntu evolve and there might be diffrence in version to version.
